# How to do image analysis in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, google-image-search, image-comparison

I am trying to verify the image which is related to the given title.

> **Once we upload the image, it needs to be verified according 
>   to the category selected.** eg, if they select a category called 'car',
>   the uploaded image should be a car image or related to car. This is my scenario.

please suggest me how could i do this using **angular js**. And kindly say me what are the steps to be taken.

- what are the angular modules will support the image analysis/ image
  comparison?
- where should i start from?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It's a huge question itself :)

Answer (score 1):

For the given scenario, first I would start with uploading the image to backend. 
I would use some directive that built for image uploading & have a route in backend to receive the image file & other `formdata`(ex: category=car).

Now, I have the image & the category name on the server. But, I don't know how to figure out that the image has given category(ex: car). I would then look for some image-reading solution. I have heard that Google Cloud Platform has a service that classifies given image. So, I would search & find the docs about that service & read/learn to how to use that service. It would be some API call to GCP server & in the response, I'd get the result.

The result might not be exactly what I wanted. Ex: `true` or `false` for the given image & category. But, by reading/inspecting the response from API call or by reading the documentation, I would know how to get the result that I wanted.

Now, I would code & get it done.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: I hope this answer would really help me, thank you so much, let me try...